# Calibre (E book management) problem on Elementary OS Luna

Tags: elementary-os, ebooks, calibre

I have had Calibre installed for some time now and it has always worked fine. Right now I tried to send a book from the Calibre library to my Kindle and I keep getting this message:

```
calibre, version 0.8.38
ERROR: Error: Error communicating with device

The reader has no storage card in this slot.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/device.py", line 81, in run
    self.result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/gui2/device.py", line 411, in _upload_books
    metadata=metadata, end_session=False)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/devices/usbms/driver.py", line 252, in upload_books
    path = self._sanity_check(on_card, files)
  File "/usr/lib/calibre/calibre/devices/usbms/device.py", line 978, in _sanity_check
    raise ValueError(_('The reader has no storage card in this slot.'))
ValueError: The reader has no storage card in this slot.
```

The book can't be sent to the device. I tried to remove Calibre and re-install it but it did not work.

**Edit 1)** 
Immediately after plugging in the kindle and running lsusb i get:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b307 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1949:0004 Lab126 Amazon Kindle 3
```

and after running dmesg | tail   i get:

```
[ 7202.714177] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci_hcd 
[ 7202.829763] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
[ 7203.831695] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kindle   Internal Storage 0100     PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 7203.832255] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 7203.837580] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] 2846720 512-byte logical blocks: (1.45    GB/1.35 GiB)
[ 7203.942275] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 7203.942287] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 0f 00 00 00
[ 7204.052235] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled,  doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 7204.323058]  sdb: sdb1
[ 7204.551835] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: Are you able to access the internal memory of the kindle using a file manager? does it mounts? What's the output of `lsusb` and `dmesg | tail` immediately after you plug the device?

Comment: Yes I am able to access the internal memory of the kindle using the file manager. So it mounts.

Comment: Good, what about my other question?

Comment: Please check my Edit 1) above

Comment: FYI: Elementary OS is not Ubuntu - it's not an Ubuntu supported derivative either, so the Ubuntu tag and title is unnecessary,

Comment: Dear Thomas I know Elementary OS is not Ubuntu but it is Ubuntu based and it uses Ubuntu 12.04 packages and repositories. It also has Ubuntu's Software Center for installing/removing software. So that's why I used the tag, but if it is making you nervous I can take it off ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lsusb and dmesg messages show - in addition to file manager - that the Kindle is mounting correctly. The actual error messages come from Calibre itself. I'd suggest updating Calibre. I installed mine from Wheezy repos and got 0.8.51 - and current version is 2.12.0. You can install it directly by running

```
sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm :D And I tip my fedora off to you my dear Sir, for you have given me what no other man was able to: access to the plethora of e-books stored in my laptop, conveniently from my mobile e-reader. My best wishes and kindest regards!

Comment: Thanks for thanks, my pleasure. There's nothing quite like a library in your pocket :D